# casting Eigen::MatrixXd matrix to cgal container types

Tags: c++, casting, eigen, cgal

In my example I get some points that form a cube and are stored in an `Eigen::MatrixXd` container, for example:

```
  // Inline mesh of a cube
  const Eigen::MatrixXd cubeV= (Eigen::MatrixXd(8,3)<<
  0.0,0.0,0.0,
  0.0,0.0,1.0,
  0.0,1.0,0.0,
  0.0,1.0,1.0,
  1.0,0.0,0.0,
  1.0,0.0,1.0,
  1.0,1.0,0.0,
  1.0,1.0,1.0).finished();
```

Now I would like to process these point in the cgal library, based for example on [this tutorial](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Poisson_surface_reconstruction_3/index.html). However you can see that the input points to the cgal functions are of the form:

```
std::vector<Pwn> points;
```

where `Pwn` corresponds to:

```
// Types
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_3 Point;
typedef Kernel::Vector_3 Vector;
typedef std::pair<Point, Vector> Pwn;
```

or in the second example of the form:

```
PointList points;
```

where again `PointList` corresponds to:

```
// Types
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef Kernel::FT FT;
typedef Kernel::Point_3 Point;
typedef CGAL::Point_with_normal_3<Kernel> Point_with_normal;
typedef Kernel::Sphere_3 Sphere;
typedef std::vector<Point_with_normal> PointList;
```

Thus, I wanted to ask how I can cast my `Eigen::MatrixXd` structure to `Pwn` or `PointList` so that I can use them with the cgal fucntions. I know that I could make for loop and push back each point individually, but my guess is that there should be a more efficient or neater way to do it instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you read more carefully the examples you'll see that you don't have to pack the points and normals in a `std::vector`. All you need is to pass points and normals containers matching the [ReadablePropertyMap](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/property_map/doc/ReadablePropertyMap.html) concept. So you have to implement a little wrapper storing a reference to a 
`MatrixXd` with a `get(const your_wrapper&,int)` free-function casting a row to a `Point_3` or `Vector_3`. Since a `MatrixXd` is by default column-wise, you'll have to perform a copy for this task and return by value. So it might be preferable to organize your points per column or to use a `Matrix<double,Dynamic,3,RowMajor>` so that when you access to a point, its coordinates are sequentially stored in memory. In this case, you might even consider doing an ugly reinterpret_cast to return by reference...

Comment: thanks for the response. Let's take it from the beginning because I am new to it. So first you say that I should initialize my points This way: `Matrix<double, Dynamic, 3, RowMajor> cubeV = (Eigen::MatrixXd(8, 3) <<
  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
  0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
  0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
  1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
  1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
  1.0, 1.0, 0.0,
  1.0, 1.0, 1.0).finished();` instead.